# ogr2ogr filegdb to postgis change geometry column and SRID

Tags: postgis, postgresql, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr

I have figured out (through the use of this thread) on how to go from a file GDB to posgreSQL using ogr2ogr. Now what I want to do is import all the feauture classes but change the geometry column to geom.

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=freelance user=postgres" C:\pathto\oakland.gdb -overwrite -progress
```

when i run this cmd ogr2ogr command it correctly imports the feature classes into postgresql but the geometry column annoyingly gets renamed to wkb_geometry. I believe there is a way to alter a column for an individual layer but how do you do it for all feature classes?

although I know its recommended to ask this in a new question but if I wanted to project/transform to another SRID while importing into PostgreSQL how would I accomplish this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a `Layer Creation Option` to your string.  The proper one is the following:
`-lco geometry_name=geom`
You can change "geom" to be whatever you wish your column name to be.

Here is your string with the option added:

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -progress -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=freelance user=postgres" C:\pathto\oakland.gdb -lco geometry_name=geom
```

If you want to change your spatial reference, you will add the following option:
`-t_srs EPSG:XXXX` where **XXXX** is your desired spatial reference.  Simply add as another option in your string.  The following shows it added, using 3500 which is the code for [NAD 83(NSRS 2007) / US State Plane Coord Sys - California Zone 6 (ftus)](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3500/).

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -progress -t_srs EPSG:3500 -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=freelance user=postgres" C:\pathto\oakland.gdb -lco geometry_name=geom
```

You will need to ensure you have the proper EPSG number for your desired spatial reference.  Those can be found at [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/)
For future reference, here is documentation for the ogr2ogr translater:  [GDAL - OGR2OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)